# how to render a dynamic image in browser

Tags: javascript, image, dynamic

I am trying to render a dynamically created image in browser.The image gets updated multiple during runtime, due to which i am trying to refresh it.But whenever refresh call in initiated browser uses the cached source, without sending a query to server.  I am working on rails 4.2 and ruby 2.2.

This is my refresh call

```
$().ready(function(){ 
$("#ajax_sub").onclick=function(){
           var par=$("#ajax_par").value
               $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: 'pages/plot',
                data: {'symbol' : par}
            }).success(function(){
                if($("#img_plot")){
                    remove_plot()
                }
                refresh_plot()
          })
        }
    })
refresh_plot=function(){
    console.log("loading image")
    img_obj=document.createElement("img")
    img_obj.id="img_plot"
    img_obj.src="/pages/stream"
    $("#plot").appendChild(img_obj)
}
```

This is console output

> > Started GET "/pages/plot?symbol=cos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-10
> >     11:35:44 -0400 Processing by PagesController#plot as */*   Parameters:
> >     {"symbol"=>"cos"} Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 0.2ms |
> >     ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
> >
> > Started GET "/pages/stream" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-10 11:35:44 -0400
> >     Processing by PagesController#stream as HTML    Sent file public/plot.png (0.3ms) Completed 200 OK in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
> >     [2015-03-10 11:35:44] WARN  Could not determine content-length of
> >     response body. Set content-length of the response or set
> >     Response#chunked = true
> >
> > Started GET "/pages/plot?symbol=sin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-10
> >     11:35:51 -0400 Processing by PagesController#plot as */*   Parameters:
> >     {"symbol"=>"sin"} Completed 200 OK in 27ms (Views: 0.2ms |
> >     ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Ajax call updates the image in controller(pages#plot) and call to "/pages/stream" initiates a send_file requests from pages#stream.
 On the first click two Get calls are initiated and after that only one.

How can i modify this behaviour, so image gets refreshed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use your browsers developer console to check what's going on. i assume that no request is issued for the image because it's source is already cached. you can circumvent this by setting all cache-headers to no-cache or append something unique to the image-url like `?somerandomstring` so your browser invalidates the cache every time.

Comment: Thanks phoet, it works like a charm. i added "?currenttime" to the image-url.